# Web-service response is encoded using OWASP ESAPI,how to decode response Client side?

Tags: ios, security, owasp, esapi

In my iOS application, i need to decode response which is encoded on server using **OWASP ESAPI**. web-service is written using java.

Comment: Any details, research? Maybe, we could ask that from the person who developed the API?

Comment: sorry but i am still researching for this topic.

Comment: How is it encoded?  Can you share a sample request/response pair?  There isn't enough information to help you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

ESAPI means **E**nterprise **S**ecurity **API**. This is a library which helps to avoid common security pitfalls.

It is not an "encoding" method per se, if you review its [encoding suggestions](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Output_Encoding_Rules_Summary) you may work out the input behind.